# Angular 4.3.1 on Safari iOS 10.3.4: TypeError null is not an object (evaluating 'n[o].outlets')

Tags: javascript, angular, mobile-safari, ios10.3.2

I am working on a Angular 4.3.1 app. The app is working mostly fine except for the Safari Browser on iOS 10.3.2.

I have the bug-tracking software "Sentry" installed and I tried my best to get my head around the two issues provided there. I am asking for hints or advice on how to investigate further.

I try to provide as much detail as possible.

**Error names:**

```
TypeError/app/vendor.6a2c8d7c7cabb4001dd2.bundle.js in Ct
error null is not an object (evaluating 'n[o].outlets')

Error/app/polyfills.473d66a7973dfd05d135.bundle.js in g
error Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'n[o].outlets') Ct@https://www.example.com/app/vendor.6a2c8d7c7cabb4001dd2.bundle.js:1:185868 https://www.example.com/app/vendor.6a2c8d7c7cabb4001dd2.bundle.js:1:185302 d@https://www.example.com/app/vendor.6a2c8d7c7cabb4001dd2.bundle.js:1:175024 Ot@https://www.example.com/app/vendor.6a2c8d7c7cabb4001dd2.bundle.js:1:185267 ft@https://www.example.com/app/vendor.6a2c8d7c7cabb4001dd2.bundle.js:1:183155 updateTargetUrlAndHref@https://www.example.com/app/vendor.6a2c8d7c7cabb4001dd2.bundle.js:1:232259 https://www.example.com/app/vendor.6a2c8d7c7cabb4001dd2.bundle.js:1:231328 __tryOrUnsub@https://www.example.com/app/vendor.6a2c8d7c7cabb4001dd2.bundle.js:1:389719 next@https://www.example.com/app/vendor.6a2c8d7c7cabb4001dd2.bundle.js:1:389005 _next@https://www.example.com/app/vendor.6a2c8d7c7cabb4001dd2.bundle.js:1:388051 next@https://www.example.com/app/vendor.6a2c8d7c7cab...
```

**Device details:**

```
browser: Mobile Safari 10.0
browser.name: Mobile Safari
device: iPhone
device.family: iPhone
level: error
logger: javascript
os: iOS 10.3.2
os.name: iOS
```

**Events (from first to latest):**

```
navigation to   #/ from /app/#/app/account 15:04:25  

xhr GET https://www.example.com/api/config [200] 15:04:25  

navigation to [Filtered] from   #/ 15:04:30  

ui.click input#email.form-control.ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-invalid[type="email"] 15:04:31  

ui.input input#email.form-control.ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-invalid[type="email"] 15:04:36  

ui.click [Filtered] 15:04:37  

ui.input [Filtered] 15:04:38  

ui.click div.text-center > button.btn.btn-fill.btn-primary[type="submit"] 15:04:39  

xhr POST [Filtered] [200] 15:04:39  

sentry QuotaExceededError: The quota has been exceeded. 15:04:39  

xhr GET https://www.example.com/api/users/1 [200] 15:04:39  

navigation to   #/app/home from [Filtered] 15:04:39  

sentry TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'n[o].outlets') 15:04:44  

ui.click div.navbar-header > button.navbar-toggle[type="button"] > span.icon-bar 15:04:45  

ui.click div.nav-container > ul.nav > li > a > p 15:04:45  

navigation to #/app/account from #/app/home 15:04:45  

exception Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'n[o].outlets')
Ct@https://www.example.com/app/vendor.6a2c8d7c7cabb4001dd2.bundle.js:1:185868
https://www.example.com/app/vendor.6a2c8d7c7cabb4001dd2.bundle.js:1:185302
d@https://www.example.com/app/vendor.6a2c8d7c7cabb4001dd2.bundle.js:1:175024
Ot@https://www.example.com/app/vendor.6a2c8d7c7cabb4001dd2.bundle.js:1:185267
ft@https://www.example.com/app/vendor.6a2c8d7c7cabb4001dd2.bundle.js:1:183155
updateTargetUrlAndHref@https://www.example.com/app/vendor.6a2c8d7c7cabb4001dd2.bundle.js:1:232259
https://www.example.com/app/vendor.6a2c8d7c7cabb4001dd2.bundle.js:1:231328
__tryOrUnsub@https://www.example.com/app/vendor.6a2c8d7c7cabb4001dd2.bundle.js:1:389719
next@https://www.example.com/app/vendor.6a2c8d7c7cabb4001dd2.bundle.js:1:389005
_next@https://www.example.com/app/vendor.6a2c8d7c7cabb4001dd2.bundle.js:1:388051
next@https://www.example.com/app/vendor.6a2c8d7c7cabb4001dd2.bundle.js:1:387723
next@https://www.example.com/app/vendor.6a2c8d7c7cabb4001dd2.bundle.js:1:726591
https://www.example.com/app/vendor.6a2c8d7c7cabb4001dd2.bundle.js:1:221087
onInvoke@https://www.example.com/app/vendor.6a2c8d7c7cabb4001dd2.bundle.js:1:12362
run@https://www.example.com/app/polyfills.473d66a7973dfd05d135.bundle.js:1:51145
https://www.example.com/app/polyfills.473d66a7973dfd05d135.bundle.js:1:48117
onInvokeTask@https://www.example.com/app/vendor.6a2c8d7c7cabb4001dd2.bundle.js:1:12278
runTask@https://www.example.com/app/polyfills.473d66a7973dfd05d135.bundle.js:1:51834
u@https://www.example.com/app/polyfills.473d66a7973dfd05d135.bundle.js:1:46666
invoke@https://www.example.com/app/polyfills.473d66a7973dfd05d135.bundle.js:1:57925
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "md-angular-cli-pro",
  "version": "1.4.4",
  "license": "http://md-pro-angular.creative-tim.com/documentation/tutorial",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-dashboard-pro-angular.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/animations": "4.3.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "2.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/common": "4.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "4.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "4.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "4.3.1",
    "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "4.3.1",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^4.1.1",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^4.1.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "^4.1.1",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^4.1.1",
    "angular2-material-datepicker": "0.5.0",
    "animate.css": "3.5.2",
    "arrive": "2.3.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.5",
    "bootstrap-material-design": "0.5.10",
    "bootstrap-notify": "3.1.3",
    "bootstrap-select": "1.12.2",
    "bootstrap-tagsinput": "0.7.1",
    "chartist": "0.9.4",
    "chartist-plugin-zoom": "0.4.0",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "datatables": "1.10.12",
    "datatables.net-bs": "1.10.12",
    "datatables.net-responsive": "2.1.1",
    "eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "4.17.47",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fullcalendar": "3.4.0",
    "googleapis": "19.0.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jasny-bootstrap": "3.1.3",
    "jquery": "1.12.4",
    "jquery-validation": "1.17.0",
    "jvectormap": "2.0.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "2.18.1",
    "moment-timezone": "0.4.0",
    "ng2-nouislider": "1.6.1",
    "ng2-select": "1.2.0",
    "ngx-chips": "1.4.6",
    "nouislider": "9.2.0",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "0.8.1",
    "pusher-js": "^4.2.2",
    "raven-js": "^3.21.0",
    "rxjs": "5.4.2",
    "sweetalert2": "6.10.1",
    "twitter-bootstrap-wizard": "1.2.0",
    "uglify-js": "1.3.5",
    "validate": "3.0.1",
    "web-animations-js": "2.2.2",
    "zone.js": "0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.3.1",
    "@types/bootstrap": "3.3.32",
    "@types/chartist": "0.9.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/jquery": "1.10.31",
    "@types/node": "6.0.73",
    "codelyzer": "2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "3.2.0",
    "karma": "1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "2.0.0",
    "tslint": "4.5.0",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  }
}
```

**My thoughts so far:**
After having removed a couple of more bugs specific to this iOS version (like a broken date-pipe) I came to the conclusion that it might be a compatibility issue related to the browser version. In specific I believe the issue is related to how angular handles routing (I derive that from the issue name 'n[o].outlets' as in router-outlets and the fact that this happens after a navigation action as you can see in the events list), but that is really all I could figure out so far.

**BTW** The QuotaExceededError is related to a check if localStorage is available (which it is not in this case).

**Thank you**
Even a little hint to how to resolve this issue or at least a shed of some light on the case is highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

**null is not an object (evaluating '$scope.userprofile.wallet_provider.toLowerCase')**

I use to face to same issue, but I resole it by if/else check,
so just find the code and put check into it.
ex:

```
if($scope.userprofile.is_prepaid && **<Put check here>**
                $scope.userprofile.wallet_provider.toLowerCase() == "del-miles"){
            if(!$scope.group_menu[4]['submenu'][1] || $scope.group_menu[4]['submenu'][1].link !== miles_menu_element.link)
                  $scope.group_menu[4]['submenu'].splice(1,0,miles_menu_element);
            }
```

So I  will one one check of "$**scope.userprofile.wallet_provider**"

Comment: the question is about angular 4, your answer is angular 1.x. Why do you think that would be helpful?